# How to send an image base64 to server windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, httprequest

I'm developing an application on windows phone 8.1 in c# that can take a picture and send it to a server (in base64) with a post request.

So my problem is that i can't find a method which still work for include my image base64 in the body on my request and send it to my server.

```
private async  void validPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Encode("ms-appx:///xx/xxx.jpg");
        try
        {
            var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            var uri = new Uri("http://x.x.x.x:x/picture/");
            string pathBase64 = Encode("ms-appx:///xx/xxx.jpg").ToString();

            Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            pairs.Add("type", "recognition");

            HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent);

            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eu)
        {

        }
    }
```

If you are a question or need more information please tell me.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to read image file from storage and convert bytes to base64 string.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(PHOTO_PATH));

        byte[] rawBytes;
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            rawBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.Length);
        }

        string base64Content = Convert.ToBase64String(rawBytes);
```

Then you have to make request with that content. I'm not sure how yours server accept requests but here is example of sending request with that string in content.

```
var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
        IBuffer content = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(base64Content, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        var request = new HttpBufferContent(content);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(SERVER_URL), request);
```